# One Docker Container Can't Connect to MySQL Container 'ECONNREFUSED'

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, npm

I'm facing an issue where one of my Docker containers is unable to connect to a MySQL container, resulting in an 'ECONNREFUSED' error. I can connect to MySQL via 'docker exec -it operatorMysql bash' and via the MySQL VS Code Extension so I know the server is up and my credentials are good.  Here's the setup and what I've tried so far.  If you could take a look at my dockerfile, docker-compose and db.js files to see if anything stands out I'd appreciate it.

I have a Docker setup with two services:

*MySQL Container:*
Exposed ports: 3306:3002
Image: mysql:latest
Container name: operatorMysql
Environment variables are correctly set, including the root password.

*Node.js Application Container:*
Image: Custom Node.js application image
Ports: Exposed 3001:3001, 9229:9229
Environment variables include MySQL-related details
I have set up a Docker network named switchboard and ensured both containers are connected to it.

Issue:
The Node.js application, specifically the MySQL connection code using npm 'mysql2', is encountering an 'ECONNREFUSED' error when attempting to connect to the MySQL container.

**Code Samples:**

*db.js (MySQL Connection File):*

```
// MySQL Connection using mysql2 package
const mysql = require('mysql2');

require('dotenv').config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'operatorMysql',
  port: 3306,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
});

console.log('MySQL Connection: ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(connection));

module.exports = connection;
```

Dockerfile.debug:

```
`# Dockerfile for the Node.js application
FROM node:lts-alpine

# Environment setup and dependencies installation
ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
EXPOSE 3002
EXPOSE 3306
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.debug.yaml:

```
`
version: '3.4'
services:
  operatorMysql:
    # MySQL container details (obfuscated)
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: operatorMysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3002:3306"
    expose:
      - "3002"
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - operatorMysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - switchboard`

  operatorMain:
`    # Node.js application container details (obfuscated)
    image: operatormain-debug
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.debug
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "9229:9229"
    command: ["node", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "./bin/www"]
    networks:
      - switchboard
    depends_on:
      - operatorMysql
    volumes:
      - ./views:/usr/src/app/views

networks:
  switchboard:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  operatorMysql_data:`
```

I appreciate any help or ideas to resolve this connection issue and enable seamless communication between the Node.js application and MySQL container. Thank you!

### Attempts to Resolve:

- I've reviewed several of the other answers on here. I've also RTFM on the docker mysql image.
- Checked Docker network settings to ensure both containers are on the same network (swicthboard).
- Verified MySQL container is up and running.  I can connect to it and get a mysql prompt.
- Changed from npm 'mysql' to 'mysql2' to address potential npm package issues.
- Attempted to edit MySQL configuration files (my.cnf/my.ini) to allow external connections, but Docker discards changes upon container rebuild.
- port forwarded 3306
- tried my container's name, 127.0.0.1, and localhost as my mysql.connection host.

Comment: Where do you specify ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'s value?

Comment: Just make sure that you are passing valid database name to connection string, your connection string should looks like "mysql://containername:port"

Comment: or,  in your db.js file, just try to replace the port number with the 3302.

Comment: There should not be `\`` characters in your YAML or `Dockerfile` files

Comment: @AnarAhmad the port to use within the Docker network is `3306`. `3302` is only mapped to the host

Comment: * ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} is getting passed from a .env file.  When I looked at docker's logs it was in the connection string so its working.

Comment: the ' character came from me indenting the code when I posted the question.  Sorry.

Comment: ROOT_PASSWORD is the password for 'root'. the other password is for my 'user'.

Comment: Where are you setting up the login for `MYSQL_USER` / `MYSQL_PASSWORD` on the `MYSQL_DATABASE` DB? You won't be able to connect with those credentials until you actually create a login in the MySQL service

Comment: Hi phil, I added a couple of users via 'CREATE USER'.  I've also setup & tested '@12.7.0.0.1' & '@localhost' as their domains to make sure that wasn't the issue.